# What is bug in C code for AVR?

Tags: avr

When we write C code the compiler can diagnose certain errors.

What is the difference between these errors and bugs?  How can we recognize bugs?

Can operating frequency effect bugs?

In the world of AVR programming are bugs a serious issue? ( I haven't found any bugs in my code yet :| ).

Comment: Why do you believe that AVR bugs are any different from, say, x86 bugs?

Comment: Hi,I think principle of the bug is same but because only code isn't casus of bug then AVR maybe creating special attention.

Comment: The potential bugs are exactly the same.  The actual bugs vastly differ because the general skill set of the average AVR user (i.e., Arduino user) is pitiful compared to the average X86 (or non-Arduino) user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "bug" is a piece of circuitry or software which doesn't perform as the author or designer intended.  It generally refers to the cause of something going wrong, but not all bugs are bad.  Often unexpected side-effects, which are literally by that definition, "bugs", are termed "undocumented features".

A bug in hardware can take many forms, from mistakes during the manufacturing (bridged tracks, for instance), incorrectly selected components (wrong values, wrong tolerances), etc., or from the manufacturer of a device making mistakes (you should read some of the "silicon errata" data sheets from some of the chip manufacturers).

A bug in software is usually down to the programmer either not having all the knowledge required to reliably create the program (not trained properly, not given full details, etc), or through successive maintenance by multiple different parties each not fully understanding the effects their changes have on the system as a whole.

It is pretty much guaranteed that any program more complex than a simple blinking light (especially anything that has any form of human interaction) will have bugs in it of some form.  Some are so minor as to be un-noticeable, but some are glaringly obvious.

There is no computer system in the world that is free from bugs, unless you count ones that never get turned on.

The most common bugs I come across in the Arduino realm are due to the programmer not understanding the programming language.  Some classic examples:

- Storing a value > 32767 in a signed (16 bit) integer.
- Overflowing arrays (wrongly assuming char[4] gives slices 0-4).
- Using = (assignment) instead of == (equality) in comparisons.
- Failure to terminate strings properly (null termination).

Answer (score 3):

A compiler will report things in your program that violate the language rules - in C, such things as missing semicolons, undefined (or mis-spelled) variables - generally anything that prevents the compiler from successfully compiling the program.  If the compiler does not report any errors, it just means that your source code complies with the rules of the language, and does not indicate that the program will actually run, or do what you want.

Bugs are errors in the logic of your program that cause it to do something other than what you want.  You can only find bugs by testing the program.

Answer (score 1):

The number of bugs that you could introduce into your code probably out pace the number of syntax type errors that the compiler can detect by more than 10000::1.

A bug in your code is any mistake in the program logic that causes the system to behave other than expected or desired.

There are just even 1000's of the very simple type mistakes that are commonly made such as these three....

1) Writing a loop that modifies the loop control variable in such a way that the loop never ends....or loops the wrong number of times.

2) Setting out to access or modify data that is pointed to by a pointer variable that has an uninitialized NULL value.

3) Accessing elements in an array that go beyond the allocated length of the array.

Good Luck Debugging!!

Comment: All three of these can be easily caught by a compiler - but unfortunately, not if you're programming in C.